# LWC performative way to use refreshApex()

Tags: lightning-web-components, refreshapex

its everything ok?

I'd would like to know if the way that i'm using the refreshApex is the correct....

I've a lot of callback in my Apex Classes from my org datas.

See in the images below:

Before all the callback's i'm calling the refreshApex to refresh my database, and after that i am able to receive the datas refreshed...

`await this.getInterestTable();`

```
    async getInterestTable() {
        await this.refreshApexGetInterestListDataRefreshed();

        await getInterestListData({priceData: this.InterestListData}).then(data => {
            if(data) {
                console.log('data1: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
                this.interestTable = this.cloneObj(data);
                this.setLabelInterest(this.interestTable);
            } else {
                console.log('data2: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
                this.interestTable = null;
            }
          }).catch(error => {
            console.log('error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            this.interestTable = null;
          });
    }
```

```
    async refreshApexGetInterestListDataRefreshed() {
        try {
            await refreshApex(this.getInterestListDataRefreshed);
        } catch(e) {
            console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
        }
    }

    @wire(getInterestListData, {priceData: '$InterestListData'})
    getInterestListDataRefreshed;
```

Comment: It would help to understand the context of getInterestTable, why it is async and why you need to call refreshApex. If you're calling imperative Apex, there's no need (that I'm aware of) to use refreshApex if you define that AuraEnabled method omitting cacheable or setting it false. Could you [edit] your question to add more info around the getInterestTable and getInterestListData functions and why they are defined the way they are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using those async/await/promises incorrectly. You need to pick *either* async/await or promise/then/catch, but not both. Further, wire methods fire automatically, so you only need to refresh if you know you've change the data and need the latest version. You definitely do not need both methods. Unless you have a need, I'd go with the simple version.

```
refreshApexGetInterestListDataRefreshed() {
    refreshApex(this.getInterestListDataRefreshed);
}

@wire(getInterestListData, {priceData: '$InterestListData'})
getInterestListDataRefreshed;
```

As far as the longer version, again use either async/await or a promise style (`.then(result => {}).catch(error => {}`).

```
    await this.refreshApexGetInterestListDataRefreshed();
```

This is wrong, because it's not a function, at least not one you have listed.

You may want to look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex) again carefully.

Comment: Hello, I understood your point, but in my case i don't know if the data change or not, I'd just need to refresh the database of my class, and after that calling my function with my logic with the database updated....

Comment: @MatheusCoelhoCampos In general, the first block of code I wrote is sufficient. You wire up the data to `getInterestListDataRefreshed`, and if you need to refresh it, you call `refreshApex(this.getInteterestListDataRefreshed)`.